# Covariate selection for double robust estimations

Tags: regression, matching

I would like to combine a matching technique and a regression analysis. I have a binary treatment and several covariates.

As I understand, I can either A) use the same covariates in the matching and the regression analysis or B) include only covariates describing the selection into treatment mechanism in the matching and add further covariates (describing the outcome mechanism) in the outcome model I estimate afterward.

Do I understand this correctly? If yes, how do I decide on one of the two options, and which papers discuss this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to decide on which variables to need to adjust for and adjust for them using the DR estimator. All variables should go into both parts of the estimator. If you have any variables that predict the outcome but not treatment, also include those in both parts of the estimator (yes, even the treatment model).

Comment: Thank you! I am using a cardinality matching approach, as I would like to proceed with a subset of my data (that is balanced in regard to the variables that determine the treatment). If I do include all variables, I need to set the imbalance tolerances (tols) higher compared to the model with fewer variables. The optimization program does not find a solution for the longer model if the tols argument is set to 0.1. Is it still better to include all variables and accept the higher imbalance (0.2)?